# What is the easiest way to give values to entries in Tkinter, python?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, append

My problem is I dont know how should I write get() method. So, I created a second empty list and when I append the oroginal list to the second one they get the values. That's obviously demand too much memory and it is too complicated (and ridiculous).

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Car = ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'Toyota']
Attributes = ['Country', 'Modell', 'Color', 'Year', 'Price']

entriesList = []
entriesList2 = []

def appendToDict():
    for i in entriesList:
        entriesList2.append(i.get())       # must be simplier way
    print(entriesList2)

for i in range(len(Attributes)):
    myLab = Label(root, text=Car[i])
    myLab.grid(row=0, column=i+1)
    myLab2 = Label(root, text=Attributes[i])
    myLab2.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    for j in range(len(Car)):
        myEntry = Entry(root)
        myEntry.grid(row=i+1, column=j+1)
        entriesList.append(myEntry)


MyButton = Button(root, text='Click me!', command=appendToDict).grid(row=7, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried this but it did not work in line 13:

```
 i =  i.get()
```

So, what's the easiest way?

Comment: I don't see any _easy_ method here, though I noticed that your list is global and hence you are appending to the same list always. Maybe create the list inside the function. You could also use `entriesList2 = [i.get() for i in entriesList]` inside the function, if your looking for a short code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

- Use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), to apply a function to all the items in an *iterable*.

  ```py
  map_object = map(lambda ent:ent.get(), entriesList)
  entriesList2 = list(map_object)
  ```
- Use list comprehension (as also mentioned in the comments by @CoolCloud)

  ```py
  entriesList2 = [i.get() for i in entriesList]
  ```